# Smart Contract Invalid Signature Solidity

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to execute the lending call function from [this Smart Contract](https://bscscan.com/address/0x1C4E9F87c7F2bCd80c89A1999d776461d41545b9#code).

The following code is JavaScript using Ethers.js to make the integration with the Smart Contract.

```
const contractAddress = "0x1C4E9F87c7F2bCd80c89A1999d776461d41545b9";

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://rpc.ankr.com/bsc"
);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, signer);

const lending = async () => {
  const id = 992581;
  const tokenId = 16587857756452;
  const price = 500000000000;
  const expiredAt = Date.now() + 60;

  const messageHash = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(
    ["uint256", "uint256", "uint256", "uint256"],
    [id, tokenId, price, expiredAt]
  );
  const signingKey = new SigningKey("0x" + privateKey);
  const signature = signingKey.signDigest(messageHash);
  const signatureString = ethers.utils.joinSignature(signature);

  const tx = await contract.lending(
    id,
    tokenId,
    price,
    expiredAt,
    signatureString,
    {
      gasLimit: 50000,
    }
  );
  const receipt = await tx.wait();

  console.log(receipt);
};
```

[This is the trx showing the error](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe90e149a52ada43f8ca9d292036c6abe91e06974ef875f2ecdea863bb3de8b49).

The Smart Contract code that verifies the signature is this one.

```
 function verifyLendingSig(
    uint256 _id,
    uint256 _tokenId,
    uint256 _price,
    uint256 _expiredAt,
    bytes calldata _signature
  ) public view {
    bytes32 criteriaMessageHash = keccak256(
      abi.encodePacked(_id, _tokenId, _price, _expiredAt)
    );
    bytes32 ethSignedMessageHash = ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(
      criteriaMessageHash
    );

    require(
      ECDSA.recover(ethSignedMessageHash, _signature) == signer,
      "invalid signature"
    );
```

Can someone show me how I can generate the signature for the lending call?

Answer (score 1):

This code checks if the signer is calling this function or not:

```
require(
  ECDSA.recover(ethSignedMessageHash, _signature) == signer,
  "invalid signature"
);
```

The current signer can be found here:
https://bscscan.com/address/0x1C4E9F87c7F2bCd80c89A1999d776461d41545b9#readContract#F7

But your address is: 0x177e294fd619c2228278e926eef9d3f8635aa094

Unless you have the private key of the signer address you can't generate the signature for the lending call.